# Providing @mention on c#

Tags: c#, regex, mention

How could I provide @mention list during typing in AutoCompleteTextBox  ?

Pattern of my mention is like:

```
   String pattern = "@[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+?(?![a-zA-Z0-9_.])";
```

Sample: consider user try to type two mention and even try to edit one of them, and text is like:

> Thank you @marvel308 and @Dav for answering my question

Comment: can you share sample input and output ?

Comment: @marvel308 I have adding a sample :)

Comment: so you want to match marvel308 and Dav ?

Comment: @marvel308 Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your regex. Try this code:

```
var input = "Thank you @marvel308 and @Dav for answering my question";
var regex = new Regex("@(?<name>[^\\s]+)");
var results = regex.Matches(input)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups["name"].Value)
    .ToArray();
```